# Seleccionar filas del DataFrame con la función query

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando con el siguiente DataFrame:

```py
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
```

Quiero filtrar el dataframe para que me salgan las personas que han sobrevivido y que son hombres:

```py
df.query('survived == 1 & sex == male')
```

Pero estoy teniendo el siguiente error que no entiendo:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/scope.py in resolve(self, key, is_local)
    199             if self.has_resolvers:
--> 200                 return self.resolvers[key]
    201 

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/collections/__init__.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940                 pass
--> 941         return self.__missing__(key)            # support subclasses that define __missing__
    942 

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/collections/__init__.py in __missing__(self, key)
    932     def __missing__(self, key):
--> 933         raise KeyError(key)
    934 

KeyError: 'male'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/scope.py in resolve(self, key, is_local)
    210                 # e.g., df[df > 0]
--> 211                 return self.temps[key]
    212             except KeyError as err:

KeyError: 'male'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

UndefinedVariableError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/24/tg28vxls25l9mjvqrnh0plc80000gn/T/ipykernel_82841/2018390203.py in <module>
----> 1 df.query('survived == 1 & sex == male')

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in query(self, expr, inplace, **kwargs)
   4058         kwargs["level"] = kwargs.pop("level", 0) + 1
   4059         kwargs["target"] = None
-> 4060         res = self.eval(expr, **kwargs)
   4061 
   4062         try:

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in eval(self, expr, inplace, **kwargs)
   4189         kwargs["resolvers"] = kwargs.get("resolvers", ()) + tuple(resolvers)
   4190 
-> 4191         return _eval(expr, inplace=inplace, **kwargs)
   4192 
   4193     def select_dtypes(self, include=None, exclude=None) -> DataFrame:

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/eval.py in eval(expr, parser, engine, truediv, local_dict, global_dict, resolvers, level, target, inplace)
    346         )
    347 
--> 348         parsed_expr = Expr(expr, engine=engine, parser=parser, env=env)
    349 
    350         # construct the engine and evaluate the parsed expression

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in __init__(self, expr, engine, parser, env, level)
    804         self.parser = parser
    805         self._visitor = PARSERS[parser](self.env, self.engine, self.parser)
--> 806         self.terms = self.parse()
    807 
    808     @property

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in parse(self)
    823         Parse an expression.
    824         """
--> 825         return self._visitor.visit(self.expr)
    826 
    827     @property

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit(self, node, **kwargs)
    409         method = "visit_" + type(node).__name__
    410         visitor = getattr(self, method)
--> 411         return visitor(node, **kwargs)
    412 
    413     def visit_Module(self, node, **kwargs):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit_Module(self, node, **kwargs)
    415             raise SyntaxError("only a single expression is allowed")
    416         expr = node.body[0]
--> 417         return self.visit(expr, **kwargs)
    418 
    419     def visit_Expr(self, node, **kwargs):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit(self, node, **kwargs)
    409         method = "visit_" + type(node).__name__
    410         visitor = getattr(self, method)
--> 411         return visitor(node, **kwargs)
    412 
    413     def visit_Module(self, node, **kwargs):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit_Expr(self, node, **kwargs)
    418 
    419     def visit_Expr(self, node, **kwargs):
--> 420         return self.visit(node.value, **kwargs)
    421 
    422     def _rewrite_membership_op(self, node, left, right):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit(self, node, **kwargs)
    409         method = "visit_" + type(node).__name__
    410         visitor = getattr(self, method)
--> 411         return visitor(node, **kwargs)
    412 
    413     def visit_Module(self, node, **kwargs):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit_BoolOp(self, node, **kwargs)
    743 
    744         operands = node.values
--> 745         return reduce(visitor, operands)
    746 
    747 

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visitor(x, y)
    737         def visitor(x, y):
    738             lhs = self._try_visit_binop(x)
--> 739             rhs = self._try_visit_binop(y)
    740 
    741             op, op_class, lhs, rhs = self._maybe_transform_eq_ne(node, lhs, rhs)

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in _try_visit_binop(self, bop)
    732         if isinstance(bop, (Op, Term)):
    733             return bop
--> 734         return self.visit(bop)
    735 
    736     def visit_BoolOp(self, node, **kwargs):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit(self, node, **kwargs)
    409         method = "visit_" + type(node).__name__
    410         visitor = getattr(self, method)
--> 411         return visitor(node, **kwargs)
    412 
    413     def visit_Module(self, node, **kwargs):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit_Compare(self, node, **kwargs)
    716             op = self.translate_In(ops[0])
    717             binop = ast.BinOp(op=op, left=node.left, right=comps[0])
--> 718             return self.visit(binop)
    719 
    720         # recursive case: we have a chained comparison, a CMP b CMP c, etc.

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit(self, node, **kwargs)
    409         method = "visit_" + type(node).__name__
    410         visitor = getattr(self, method)
--> 411         return visitor(node, **kwargs)
    412 
    413     def visit_Module(self, node, **kwargs):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit_BinOp(self, node, **kwargs)
    530 
    531     def visit_BinOp(self, node, **kwargs):
--> 532         op, op_class, left, right = self._maybe_transform_eq_ne(node)
    533         left, right = self._maybe_downcast_constants(left, right)
    534         return self._maybe_evaluate_binop(op, op_class, left, right)

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in _maybe_transform_eq_ne(self, node, left, right)
    452             left = self.visit(node.left, side="left")
    453         if right is None:
--> 454             right = self.visit(node.right, side="right")
    455         op, op_class, left, right = self._rewrite_membership_op(node, left, right)
    456         return op, op_class, left, right

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit(self, node, **kwargs)
    409         method = "visit_" + type(node).__name__
    410         visitor = getattr(self, method)
--> 411         return visitor(node, **kwargs)
    412 
    413     def visit_Module(self, node, **kwargs):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py in visit_Name(self, node, **kwargs)
    543 
    544     def visit_Name(self, node, **kwargs):
--> 545         return self.term_type(node.id, self.env, **kwargs)
    546 
    547     def visit_NameConstant(self, node, **kwargs):

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/ops.py in __init__(self, name, env, side, encoding)
     96         tname = str(name)
     97         self.is_local = tname.startswith(LOCAL_TAG) or tname in DEFAULT_GLOBALS
---> 98         self._value = self._resolve_name()
     99         self.encoding = encoding
    100 

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/ops.py in _resolve_name(self)
    113 
    114     def _resolve_name(self):
--> 115         res = self.env.resolve(self.local_name, is_local=self.is_local)
    116         self.update(res)
    117 

~/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/scope.py in resolve(self, key, is_local)
    214                 from pandas.core.computation.ops import UndefinedVariableError
    215 
--> 216                 raise UndefinedVariableError(key, is_local) from err
    217 
    218     def swapkey(self, old_key: str, new_key: str, new_value=None) -> None:

UndefinedVariableError: name 'male' is not defined
```

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Al hacer `query` debes tener en cuenta que las comparaciones con `string` necesitan comillas, si utilizas comillas sencillas `'` para la consulta entonces necesitas comillas dobles `"` para la comparación, y viceversa.

Ejemplo 1 (Con comillas simples para la consulta y dobles para la comparación):

```
df.query('survived == 1 & sex == "male"')
```

Ejemplo 2 (Con comillas dobles para la consulta y simples para la comparación):

```
df.query("survived == 1 & sex == 'male'")
```

En ambos casos devuelve un `dataframe` filtrado de `109` filas

En este caso `survived` es una columna de valores numéricos `0` y `1` por lo que no necesita las comillas para la comparación